# Logar com usuário de rede (LDAP)

Tags: java

Tenho um servidor LDAP na empresa e para logar na máquina é necessário um usuário de rede. Gostariamos que depois que o usuário ja está logado na máquina, ao utilizar a rede ou alguma aplicação na intranet não seja necessário informar novamente usuário e senha. Que por via LDAP fosse possível emitir alguma autenticação em que o login fosse passado de forma automático.

Tem como essa possibilidade? Se sim alguém conhece uma maneira para eu me basear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenho parte da solução, espero que o ajude. Com a classe abaixo é possível se conectar ao active directory via java.

Há um método nesta classe, o authentication, o qual espera dois parâmetros, o username e a senha do LDAP.

Você pode utilizá-lo de duas formas:

1. Validar usuário e senha ( para isto informe nele o usuário e senha do LDAP, ex: `authentication("filipe","senhateste"));`
2. Validar se o usuário existe no LDAP (para isto informe o usuário e a senha), contudo a senha deve ficar em branco por ex: `authentication("filipe","")`

Há um exemplo na última classe desta resposta.

Com esta classe você teria condições de permitir que um usuário do LDAP se autenticasse em seu sistema com o mesmo login e senha da rede.

Faltaria encontrar um método de descobrir, talvez nos diretórios do windows, se há o usuário do LDAP.

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.naming.AuthenticationException;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class LdapAuthentication {  


    /** 
     * Classe que realiza a conexão e autenticação ao LDAP 
     *  
     * @author Adriano Anderson 
     */  

    /* 
     * Singleton 
     */  
    protected static LdapAuthentication instanceLdap;  

    /* 
     * Implementação do Initial context para LDAP 
     */  
    public static String INITIAL_CTX = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory";  

    /* 
     * Servidor LDAP 
     */  
    public static String SERVIDOR = "ldap://10.92.10.24:389"; //Defina aqui o ip onde está o ldap. o que vem após os ":" é a porta do ldap 

    /* 
     * Tipo de conexão realizada 
     */  
    public static String CONNECTION_TYPE = "simple";  

    /* 
     * Nome distinto do admin 
     */  
    public static String ADMIN_DN = "proxy_user";  

    /* 
     * Senha 
     */  
    public static String ADMIN_PW = "123456";  

    /* 
     * Diretório Base 
     */  
    public static String BASE_DN = "dc=cpbad,dc=cpb,dc=com,dc=br";  

    /* 
     * Mensagem de Erro de Conexão ao Ldap 
     */  
    public static String MSG_ERROR_LDAP_CONNECTION = "Não foi possível obter um contexto LDAP";  

    /* 
     * Mensagem de Erro sobre Validação do Login e Password 
     */  
    public static String MSG_ERROR_LDAP_VALIDATION_USER = "Username ou Password Inválida";  

    private LdapAuthentication() {  
        super();  
    }  

    /** 
     * Obtém a mesma instância de LdapAuthentication para todas as chamadas 
     *  
     * @author Adriano Anderson 
     * @return um objeto LdapAuthentication 
     */  
    public static LdapAuthentication getInstance() {  

        if (instanceLdap == null) {  
            instanceLdap = new LdapAuthentication();  
        }  

        return instanceLdap;  
    }  

    /** 
     * Método responsável por realizar a chamada para autenticação via ldap do 
     * login e password passados como parâmetros. 
     *  
     * @author Adriano Anderson 
     */  
    public boolean authentication(String login, String password) {  

        DirContext ctx = null;  
        SearchControls sc = null;  
        String filtro = null;  
        NamingEnumeration cursor = null;  
        boolean bResult = false;  

        /* 
         * Cria conexão padrão com LDAP 
         */  
        ctx = createLdapConnection();  

        if (ctx != null) {  

            sc = new SearchControls();  
            sc.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);  
            /* 
             * Define atributos de retorno da consulta 
             */  
            String[] atributosParaRetornar = { "distinguishedName","sAMAccountType" };  
            sc.setReturningAttributes(atributosParaRetornar);  
            /* 
             * Especifica login para consulta 
             */  
            filtro = "(&(sAMAccountName=" + login + "))";  

            try {  
                cursor = ctx.search(BASE_DN, filtro, sc);  

                if (cursor.hasMoreElements()) {  

                    SearchResult result = (SearchResult) cursor.nextElement();  
                    Attributes att = result.getAttributes();  
                    String dn = (String) att.get("distinguishedName").get();  
                    //String st = (String) att.get("sAMAccountType").get();

                    /* 
                     * Se o login existe, tenta autenticar no LDAP com a senha 
                     * fornecida pelo usuário 
                     */  
                    bResult = validateUser(dn, password);  
                }  

            } catch (NamingException e) {  
                System.out.println(MSG_ERROR_LDAP_CONNECTION);  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
        }  
        return bResult;  
    }  

    /** 
     * Método responsável por realizar a conexão padrão com o Ldap. 
     *  
     * @author Adriano Anderson 
     */ 

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private DirContext createLdapConnection() {  

        DirContext ctx = null;  
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();  

        // Especifica INITIAL CONTEXT  
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CTX);  

        // Especifica o IP/Nome e a porta do servidor LDAP  
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, SERVIDOR);  

        // Usuário ADMIN  
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, ADMIN_DN);  

        // Senha ADMIN  
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, ADMIN_PW);  

        // Tipo de Conexão  
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, CONNECTION_TYPE);  

        try {  
            // Cria um Initial Context  
            ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);  

        } catch (NamingException e) {  
            System.out.println(MSG_ERROR_LDAP_CONNECTION);  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
        return ctx;  
    }  

    /** 
     * Método responsável por realizar a validação do login no Ldap. O campo dn 
     * é distinguished name formado anteriormente a partir da consulta do login 
     * no Ldap. 
     *  
     * @author Adriano Anderson 
     */  
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private boolean validateUser(String dn, String senha) {  

        DirContext ldapCtx = null;  
        boolean bResult = false;  

        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();  

        // Especifica INITIAL CONTEXT  
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CTX);  

        // Especifica o IP/Nome e a porta do servidor LDAP  
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, SERVIDOR);  

        // Ldap Distingued Name  
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, dn);  

        // Senha Usuário  
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, senha);  

        // Tipo de Conexão  
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, CONNECTION_TYPE);  

        try {  
            // Cria um Initial Context  
            ldapCtx = new InitialDirContext(env);


        } catch (AuthenticationException auEx) {  
            System.out.println(MSG_ERROR_LDAP_VALIDATION_USER);  
            auEx.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (NamingException ne) {  
            System.out.println(MSG_ERROR_LDAP_CONNECTION);  
            ne.printStackTrace();  
        } finally {  

            if (ldapCtx != null) {  
                bResult = true;  
            }  
        }  

        return bResult;  
    }  
}
```

Segue a classe para teste da conexão:

```
public class TesteLdap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        

        Boolean autenticado = LdapAuthentication.getInstance().authentication("weles", "algumasenha");

        if (autenticado)
        {
            System.out.println("Autenticado");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Não Autenticado!");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Weles, é justamente isso que eu estava indo atrás. Vou verificar o método para fazer o teste se o usuário existe no ldap e assim que possível ja vou fazendo os testes para ativar este login automático.

Comment: Maraviha @Fillipe Sanches. Boa sorte! Se puder ajudar em algo mais me avise! Por favor marque a questão com mais, isso ajuda na reputação. Obrigado!

Comment: -1 devido a: **(a)** Campos `public static` sem ter o `final` (ou seja, variáveis globais). **(b)** Javadocs mal-formados. **(c)** Utilização incorreta e inadequada do padrão singleton. **(d)** Notação húngara. **(e)** Tratamento inadequado de exceções escondendo erros e poluindo o `System.out`. **(f)** Métodos que confundem erro de conexão com erro de autenticação. **(g)** Desprezo não justificado pelos tipos genéricos. **(h)** Uso inadequado do `finally`.

Answer (score 1):

Oi. Sei que essa pergunta é antiga, mas fui direcionado até aqui devido a um problema que amigos meus estavam tendo. Criei um projetinho para fazer autenticação e coloquei ele no formato de uma biblioteca no [**GitHub**](https://github.com/victorwss/Simple-LDAP), que chamei de Simple-LDAP.

Para utilizar, você pode fazer o seguinte:

1. Primeiro inclua a biblioteca do Simple-LDAP no seu projeto. A melhor forma de fazer isso é adicionando o JAR como biblioteca. Se não conseguir fazer isso ou estiver com pressa ou coisa assim, pode até apenas copiar e colar os arquivos ".java" dele no seu projeto, respeitando os pacotes.
2. Depois, acrescente a classe que se segue. É necessário apenas configurar os parâmetros de conexão adequadamente:

   ```
   package teste;

   import ninja.javahacker.simpleldap.IncorrectPasswordException;
   import ninja.javahacker.simpleldap.LdapAuthenticator;
   import ninja.javahacker.simpleldap.LdapConnectionException;
   import ninja.javahacker.simpleldap.UserNotFoundException;

   public class Auth {

       private static final String LDAP_SERVER = "your.ldap.server.hostname";
       private static final int LDAP_PORT = 3268;
       private static final String ROOT_DN = "ROOT_LDAP_DN";
       private static final String ROOT_PW = "ROOT_LDAP_PASSWORD";
       private static final String DN = "dc=yourorganization,dc=example,dc=com";

       private static final LdapAuthenticator AUTH = createAuthenticator();

       private static LdapAuthenticator createAuthenticator() {
           try {
               return new LdapAuthenticator(LDAP_SERVER, LDAP_PORT, ROOT_DN, ROOT_PW, DN);
           } catch (LdapConnectionException x) {
               throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(x);
           }
       }

       private Auth() {}

       public static void authenticate(String login, String password) throws LdapConnectionException, UserNotFoundException, IncorrectPasswordException {
           AUTH.authenticate(login, password);
       }

       public static boolean tryAuthenticate(String login, String password) throws LdapConnectionException {
           return AUTH.tryAuthenticate(login, password);
       }

       public static String findUserDn(String login) throws LdapConnectionException, UserNotFoundException {
           return AUTH.findDn(login);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Em seguida, você pode testar a conexão assim:

   ```
   package teste;

   import ninja.javahacker.simpleldap.IncorrectPasswordException;
   import ninja.javahacker.simpleldap.LdapConnectionException;
   import ninja.javahacker.simpleldap.UserNotFoundException;

   public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws LdapConnectionException, UserNotFoundException, IncorrectPasswordException {
           Auth.authenticate("usuario aqui", "Senha aqui");
           System.out.println("Logado com sucesso!");
       }
   }
   ```

   Se a autenticação for bem sucedida, vai aparecer a mensagem no console. Se não for, a exceção descrevendo qual é o erro que aconteceu (problema de conexão, usuário não existente ou senha incorreta) é lançada.

   Ou se preferir, faça assim:

   ```
   package teste;

   import ninja.javahacker.simpleldap.LdapConnectionException;

   public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws LdapConnectionException {
           System.out.println("Logado: " + Auth.tryAuthenticate("usuario aqui", "Senha aqui"));
       }
   }
   ```

   Nesse caso acima, o método `tryAuthenticate` retorna verdadeiro ou falso para dizer se a autenticação deu certo ou não. Se ocorrer problema de conexão (e por isso nem der para saber se a senha está certa ou não), uma exceção é lançada.